# Stacked bar chart options in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, charts, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I need a stacked bar chart that looks something like below -

[image]

What are my options to implement the above in AWS? should I use Cloudwatch Dashboard or AWS Quicksight?